# Error in ADFS Authentication ASP.NET Core + Angular without Oauth

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, adfs3.0

when I try to call an API from the frontend I get this error:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ts5g.png)

Error Text:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://XXX.XXXXX.it/adfs/ls/?wtrealm=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44343%2F&wa=wsignin1.0&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44343%2Fsignin-wsfed&wctx=CfDJ8LoBGisiQ49KrBHVuNcYRJKcy1bIbno2NikzQL0qT4dTl4qGoCM3AP2GXKeW9sf0rYN0aYQysbNLx-09dkgcUwkk5dFM9ETH8iFmlkrc-mV6cT7VjFM1zY2kpj1xmw3rFiNDnXr9uaekQd2lGa1Re6KXVcvRKFtYR7kgA_EKH5elgtY-Cu2oeFuRoKuPkXcLcJhYP7Mr4wKQk2AJaTjMDBM' (redirected from 'https://localhost:44343/XXXXX') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is the implementation of authentication with WsFederation and the enabling of CORS:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
                {
                    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddWsFederation(options =>
                {
                    options.Wtrealm = _configuration["ida:Wtrealm"];
                    options.MetadataAddress = _configuration["ida:ADFSMetadata"];
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,

                    };

                })
                .AddCookie();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.ConfigureExceptionHandler();

            app.UseMvc();
}
```

Is it the wrong way?

the only solution is to use OAuth in Angular?

ADFS version is 3.0.

Can you help me??? Thanks

Comment: Can you add also .AllowCredentials() to your builder in app.UseCors and try again?

Comment: yes but the problem has not been solved

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your error message as text in your question so others with the same problem can find it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Set CORS setting in ADFS

Just in case anyone else is looking for it you can set it with the Set-

AdfsResponseHeaders powershell command

```
Set-AdfsResponseHeaders -EnableCORS $true
Set-AdfsResponseHeaders -CORSTrustedOrigins http://localhost, https://contoso.com
Get-AdfsProperties | select EnableCORS, CORSTrustedOrigins
```